# How to isolate voice from audio file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio, fft, naudio

I'm writing a software to compare two singers singing ability in a competitive way. First, The user adds a music file which is original from the original singer. Then, the software has to automatically isolate the voice from the audio and then compare it with recorded audio by user.

So far, I am not able to find a source or any other tool to use this FFT method to isolate the voice.

Comment: To isolate the voice from a recording with instruments is higher science and I think impossible. There is no way to decide, which belongs to the voice and which to some instruments. You can filter the frequencies (with FFT) that are typical for voices, but you get all the noise that the instruments produce in this frequency range, too. Everything further is rocket science. And "compare singing ability" with two audio files, seems to be even more rocket science. So unless you are a genius hacker at a research facility, you are lost I think.

Comment: are you saying that I could not compare voices of two files? cause I am supposed to submit this project as soon as possible and I need to compare these two voices somehow and show percentage of how much of a similarity of a pitch

Comment: I don't know you and can not know if you could do that. But your question lets me assume you are not an expert and researcher in audio signal processing. The nearest thing I know of that is available on the market is the singstar game for the playstation. But as far as I know, the only thing it does is to calculate the pitch out of the frequency from the microphone you sing into and compare it with the expected data for this point in time of the song.

Comment: I think the easiest possible thing would be to have two audios with only voices. Then you could process them with FFT and perhaps calculate the pitch for each millisecond and compare both data. Perhaps this could help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm
Or look at other results from this search:
https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=voice+pitch+fft

Comment: You are right. I am not an expert in audio signaling. I am more of a business application developer and analyst. That's why I'm struggling so hard

Answer (score 8):

There are ways of seperating seperate sounds in audio, but they can be very tricky and require a lot of knowledge about digital signal processing.

There is actually an example of what you're talking about demonstrated by Dr. Alan Openheimer in his MIT lecture series on digital signal processing. (around 9:50 in the video) If you're serious about doing this, then going through his videos is quite useful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkvEM5Y3N60

The best thing I can give you is probably the research from University of York where they've worked on this quite a bit. If you go through some of their papers you should find some examples of how to achieve this.

http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~jes1/Audio_Signal_Processing_Research_Demos1.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an SDK or API or something?

Comment: @cegprakash that was funny :)